# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userName' not found on type java.lang.String Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am only entering the code which is giving me error

My controller class has the following method

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/displayUser")
public String displayUsers(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("Users", userDetailsService.listUsers());
    return "displayUser";

}
```

My Service class has the following method

```
public List<UserDetails> listUsers()
{
    Query que=hibernateSessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("select userName from UserDetails");
    List<UserDetails> listOfUsers=null;
    try {

        listOfUsers=  que.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    return listOfUsers;
}
```

I want to list all the usernames on my JSP, so I used JSTL

```
       <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Display User</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:forEach var="Users" items="${Users}">
${Users.userName}
</c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error for the above code.

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userName' not found on type java.lang.String
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.displayUser_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(displayUser_jsp.java:119)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.displayUser_jsp._jspService(displayUser_jsp.java:80)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Try changing `<c:forEach var="Users" items="${Users}">` to `<c:forEach var="User" items="${Users}">` and check ! Just change the `var` attribute such that it doesn't matches the already scoped attribute `Users` .

Comment: Thanks @the new idiot: I figured the problem out. It was my mistake, username is actually a string and I am creating a list if objects. I just changed to string and referred it and it works fine.